# what is the difference between Synchronization and Mutex

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

what is the difference between Mutex,Semaphore and synchronization.

Is synchronization is way to achieve mutex in java.

Comment: i know that mutex is a binary semaphore also semaphore can be achieved in java.I am confused with synchronized block or method.Is synchronized is way to achieve mutex in java?

Comment: Voted to re-open because the question asks about Java's `synchronized` keyword, and the "duplicate" says nothing about that. On the other hand, the OP has shown little effort to find his own answer, so maybe the question should remain closed for that reason.